# How to change the country code for a specific country

Tags: magento2, locale, country-regions

is it possible to change the country code for a specific country?

```
DE -> GER
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: first of all, why do you want to do that, this i definitly not a good idea to change this globally, if you f.e. want to show somewhere in the frontend 'GER' instead of 'DE' do it there.
Theoretically you could modify the value in the according database table, but there are some spots like in the zend framework where 'DE' is still hardcoded. You won't be able to modify it there.